# HTML Editor portable para c# WinForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, mono

Mi pregunta es si conocen de algún control que permita editar contenido HTML, negritas, imágenes, tablas... pero con la condición de que sea portable a Mono (Windows / Linux)

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de un componente como este

[WinForms HTML Editor](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlnol/2011/07/30/winforms-html-editor/)

entiendo que este debería poder aplicarse a otras plataformas

Sino vas a tener que evaluar controles de terceros como ser

[HTMLUI Control](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/htmlui)

este menciona que completamente independiente del IE por lo tanto no deberia estar usando el WebBrowser internamente, seria cuestion de evaluarlo

Comment: Me temo que al estar basado en un WebBrowser es incompatible con mono, precisamente esto estoy evitando

Comment: porque dices que esta basado en el WebBrowser ? en parte ves que lo utiliza

Comment: una duda, como haces correr winform en Mono ? no sera que usas xaml

Comment: No, simplemente al no usar pinvokes ni apis del sistema, el mismo ejecutable con mono corre sin recompilar

Answer (score 0):

Al no poder depender de un control ActiveX, COM, o similar, creo que lo mejor es que te bases en un [RichTextBox](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3ASystem.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox) para poder hacer lo que quieres, aunque va a ser mucho más trabajo que emplear un control de terceros, claro.